# Electron: Sharing the same project folder between macOS and Windows

Tags: windows, macos, electron, cross-platform, yarnpkg

### Goal

I've read many Electron tutorials about app bootstrapping and build pipeline and had assumed that you could have a single project to handle a cross-platform action.

But after numerous failures in the packaging and build process, I finally realized that maybe my assumption is wrong.

### Problem

Here is my desired workflow based on electron-forge:

#### 1. Create app skeleton on Windows

```sh
yarn create electron-app my-app

cd my-app

yarn add my-dependency

yarn start

yarn make
```

This all went well. Now onto macOS

#### 2. Transfer project to macOS for a ride

On macOS, running the app will lead to an error

```sh
cd my-app

yarn start
```

The error looks like this

```sh
$ yarn start
yarn run v1.22.4
$ electron-forge start
✔ Checking your system
✔ Locating Application
✔ Preparing native dependencies: 1 / 1
✔ Launching Application
/path/to/my-app/node_modules/electron/dist/electron.exe: /path/to/my-app/node_modules/electron/dist/electron.exe: cannot execute binary file
error Command failed with exit code 126.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

So I blindly reinstall electron on macOS

```sh
yarn add electron

yarn start

yarn make
```

Things work fine on macOS.

Now back to Windows.

#### 3. Travel back to Windows to double-check

This time. I got the similar problem as in Step #2. The Windows distribution now has the wrong Electron binary.

### Findings

I found this file constantly getting overwritten even if I merge carefully when transferring project files between Windows and macOS.

```sh
my-app/node_modules/electron/path.txt
```

It contains a hardcoded path to Electron executable:

macOS

```sh
Electron.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron
```

Windows:

```sh
electron.exe
```

### Workarounds

I could add pre-build steps against this by copying predefined metadata to the project folder depending on the current platform. But a hack like this sounds lame for a framework like Electron.

### Question

So to me this metadata arrangement makes it difficult to share the same project between Windows and macOS. I can't imagine Electron developers working like this.

So What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you shouldn't commit `node_modules` at all. Some post installation scripts may compile packages for a specific OS and the folder is usually huge.

Also, you shouldn't commit any result of a build, package or compile command. Typically, `dist` folders should be ignored.

Your repository should only contains code and configuration files.
The idea is that it makes no sense to commit these files and folders as you have all the required steps in order to reproduce the result on any machine: your windows computer, your macOS computer, your CI environment, etc. For example (these are pseudo-commands):

1. `npm i` or `npm ci`
2. `npm run build`
3. `electron package`
4. etc

So you should add all these folders to you `.gitignore` file:

```
# compiled output
/dist
/tmp
/out-tsc
/packages

# dependencies
/node_modules
```

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I'm at a place where internet access is heavily restricted. So I thought about caching everything on SCM. Looks like a terrible idea.

Comment: There may be pros for committing the node_modules, but most of the time it does not provide any real benefit. Also, NPM caches everything locally on your computer (in the user folder). 
This article is a good summary: https://flaviocopes.com/should-commit-node-modules-git/

Comment: Question: Should I gitignore `yarn.lock` or similar locks at the project root?

Comment: No, you should definitely commit them. They lock the version of installed dependencies, so re-installation is even more reproductible: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/yarn-lock/